# Big websites that were developed using Ember.js

Tags: client-side, ember.js, robustness

I'm considering using Ember.js to develop my new websites.

I'm not sure how stable & how much it being used by the community for big projects.

1. Would you recommend using it?
2. Do you know big websites that are using it?

Thanks,
Lior

Comment: This was very helpful and constructive for me and while not perfect has been important to me.  PS> A simple google did not help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple googling would've given you these:

1: [Quora: What are the advantages of using Ember.js?](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-of-using-Ember-js)
2: [Top 8 Best Looking SproutCore Websites](http://www.appnovation.com/top-8-best-looking-sproutcore-websites) (SproutCore 2.0 was recently renamed to Ember.js -- [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SproutCore))

Comment: We developed our site https://beta.bondable.com using EmberJS.

Comment: Some simple googling brought me here